# Print variable name and value to console

Tags: c#

I want to create a debug utility function to print a variable's name and value to the console, like
this:

```
float my_variable = 10;
debug_print(my_variable);
```

And have the output be `"my_variable = 10"`

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`nameof` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) to get the name of a variable (though you have to pass the variable to it, so not sure how that's helpful since you already know the name), and then show the value:

```
Debug.Print($"{nameof(my_variable)} = {my_variable}");
```

Which is the same as:

```
Debug.Print($"my_variable = {my_variable}");
```

However, if this were put into a method, it would output the name of the method argument variable, not the name of the variable you pass in.